# Pattern search within directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, exec

How do we find a particular pattern in files and sub-directories within a directory?
An exact word can be searched for using a find grep and exec.
But how do we find something like below:
`'match=true'` 
where there may or may not be multiple spaces around '='.

Comment: `grep match *= *true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds `match=true` with zero or more (`*`) whitespace characters (`\s`) around the equals sign (<kbd>Tab</kbd>, although uncommon between non-whitespace characters, would also be a valid character around an equals sign in many languages):

```
grep 'match\s*=\s*true'
```

If you want to match exactly zero or one whitespace, you can use `\?` instead of `*` above.